# What is ic_launcher_backgroud.xml used for on Andorid Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-icons

So I have a file that is ic_launcher_backgroud.xml that is a file of the app icon but I don´t see any changes on the icon when changing this component, what is the use of that file? Is it really important? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by " changing this component"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ofcourse it is important. You have to read this article why it is mandatory and how it is used [Adaptive Icon](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive).

Your app icon is always be in 2 part, first part is ic_launcher_foreground which will be your icon and ic_launcher_background this will be either any color or any background behind tour icon.
As Android have multiple launcher application in Play Store it is possible others launcher are showing different shape of icon and for that Android taking background icon so that it fit for all type of icon and it didn't cropped in other launcher icon.